# Reorder items in ListView using drag and drop

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps

I tried to reorder items in a ListView using drag and drop gestures.

`In the "Drop" method I don't know how to get a reference to the "dropped" element, I only get reference to the "target drop" element.`

See below:

```
private void Grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            ReorderItem draggedElement = (e.OriginalSource as Grid).DataContext as ReorderItem;
            ReorderItem targetElement = ((Grid)sender).DataContext as ReorderItem;

            Debug.WriteLine("Dragged element is:" + draggedElement.Index);
            Debug.WriteLine("Drag target element is:" + targetElement.Index);
        }
```

The reorder is between 0 and 1 indexes. The console index is both 1 :(

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanReorderItems="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="{Binding Color}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              AllowDrop="True"
                              Drop="Grid_Drop">
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `DragEventArgs.Data` is for. Create a [`DataPackage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage) of the dragged item in the `DragItemsStarting` event. The `DataPackage` is passed between the two events.

Edit:

That enables dragging between two `ListView`s. According to the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.canreorderitems.Aspx):

"To enable users to reorder items using drag-and-drop interaction, you must set both the `CanReorderItems` and `AllowDrop` properties to true."

This should fix your issues.

Comment: `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanReorderItems="True" DragItemsStarting="MyListView_DragItemsStarting">`

Comment: Yes, I figured out but now the problem is that the "Grid_Drop" is called before "MyListView_DragItemsStarting"...

Comment: The drop event is set on the Grid INSIDE a ListView.ItemContainer.. could be this the issue? maybe I must set the drop event on the ListView.ItemContainerStyle but don't know how...

Comment: In fact, the "ReorderListView_DragItemsStarting" isn't called at all...<ListView x:Name="ReorderListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      CanReorderItems="True"
                      DragItemsStarting="ReorderListView_DragItemsStarting">

Comment: Ah, one thing noticed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.canreorderitems.Aspx) is "To enable users to reorder items using drag-and-drop interaction, you must set both the `CanReorderItems` and `AllowDrop` properties to true." Give that a try.

Comment: Thank you @Nate Diamond. It works pretty well. Isn't the first time when you save with your answers...Thanks again

Comment: There is no property `CanReorderItems` in ListView :/

Comment: The link in my response disagrees. The reference doc claims that it exists in `ListViewBase`, of which `ListView` is one.

Comment: @NateDiamond  [wpf ListView inherits from ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) and does not have a CanReorderItems property.

Comment: Ah, this must be the confusion between the two tags in the main question: `wpf` and `windows-store-apps`. That should probably be fixed since the question was apparently about `windows-store-apps`, even if it used `xaml`.

Answer (score 5):

Why re-invent the wheel when someone's done it already.  Check out 
https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop.  Its available as a NuGet package as well.

although the documentation uses a `ListBox`, I use it with a `ListView`